# django-wiki: how to list all articles under root article

Tags: python, django, django-wiki

I am a newbie in Django and am currently building a site. I have downloaded [django-wiki ver 0.4a3](https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki/blob/master/docs/installation.rst) to have a wiki app for my site. Everything works fine, out-of-the-box. But instead of showing the root article as the main page, how can I show a list of all articles under the root article, so users can just click on any child article to open up that article? At the moment, users have to click a menu option to browse up one level or to browse at the current level to have a listing of all articles at that given level. I find this rather tedious. I rather have an "Windows Explorer tree-and-branch-like" navigation, e.g.,

```
root
|_child 1
| |_child 1.1
| |_child 1.2
|
|_child 2
| |_child 2.1
|   |_child 2.1.1
|
|_child 3
```

Please note I am asking how to get a list all of articles under the root article, not how to create a template to implement the tree-and-branch articles navigator. Once I know how to get a listing of all articles, I think I can implement the necessary HTML and CSS to have that kind of navigator. I appreciate any pointers.

P.S. I have previously tried the official django-wiki google support group, but I think the support there is dead and buried. My two questions there are neither answered, let alone read (I only get 1 view -- which is actually my view count).

Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Solved.]**

Make a copy of `article.html` originally located at `wiki/templates/wiki/` and place this copy in your own project's `templates/wiki/` directory. At the place where you want to place the tree directory, add something like the following lines:

```
<!-- article.html -->
...
<h4>List of articles</h4>
<ul>
  <!-- Need to get the first article (root) -->
  {% url 'wiki:get' path=urlpath.root.path as rootpath %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ rootpath }}">
      {{ urlpath.root.article.current_revision.title }}
    </a>
  </li>

  <!-- Now get all the descendent articles of the root -->
  {% for child in urlpath.root.get_descendants %}
    <!-- Don't list articles marked for deletion -->
    {% if not child.is_deleted %}
      {% with ''|center:child.level as range %}
        {% for _ in range %}<ul>{% endfor %}
        {% url 'wiki:get' path=child.path as childpath %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ childpath }}">
            {{ child.article.current_revision.title }}
          </a>
        </li>
        {% for _ in range %}</ul>{% endfor %}
      {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can fancy up the code above. I am new in Django (and to using django-wiki), so this might not be the cleanest or most efficient way, but the above works as expected for me.

Advantage:

- The list of articles are always updated, so any deleted articles are removed and inserted new articles are shown.
- The tree-like hierarchy visually shows all the available articles and their relationships with one another. This visual depiction is far, far better than the default's which is hard to even know how many articles exist or how far deep articles are nested.

Disadvantage:

- According to the django-wiki's source code, `get_descendents` method is an expensive call, but for my small site, I have not noticed any penalty hits (so far).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your structure is no more than 10 deep:

```
[article_list depth:10]
```

Put this in your root article.